# Schengen visa application timeframe

Tags: visas, schengen, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan residing in UAE. I am planning to apply for a Schengen visa for my family from the Italian consulate.

Question - What would be the minimum and maximum time frame from the date of application to the date of departure? So that I can plan and apply accordingly.

Comment: I would just note that it should be "Schengen *visas*," plural, since each traveler needs his or her own visa.

Answer (score 1):

With luck and a fair wind, a Schengen decision can be made on the same day it is submitted, but for *judicious* planning purposes, a Schengen decision will normally be reached within 15 days of submission, and it is reasonable to assume this to be your minimum expected turn-around time.

The maximum decision time can be up to 60 days...

> As a general rule, once a Schengen visa application is submitted to
>   the Consulate, a decision is taken by the Consulate within 15 calendar
>   days. This period may be extended up to 30 days or 60 days. More
>   information is available on our website on this page: [Processing of a
>   visa application](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/visa_application/index_en.htm)

Source: [Frequently asked questions](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf)

The authority to extend to 30 or 60 days is given in [Article 23](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex%3A32006R0562) of the Borders Code.

Italian consulates use the [Visa Facilitation Centre scheme](http://www.vfsglobal.com/) so a personal appearance at the consulate is not required but depending upon where your family is vis-a-vis their nearest centre additional travel days may be needed to obtain a VFS appointment for enrolling their biometrics.

Comment: Dear all...Thank you for your valuable responses. Highly appreciated. I take it as 15 - 60 days.

Comment: Also, note that Application cannot be submitted more than 90 days before intended entry date..